# Xampp Error: Apache shutdown because of the port 80?

Tags: java, apache

i installed xampp on my pc and get this error:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
23:00:50  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
23:00:50  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
23:00:50  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
23:00:50  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
23:00:50  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
23:00:50  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I have no skype open and if i change the port of apache i still get this error.

Can anybody help me please! Thanks!